# named propagated changes with incrementing the serial number

Tags: dns, bind, named

Listed below are the log entries from the last 2 times I reloaded named, you can see that the serial number didn't change (a little boneheaded oversight). When I got into the office on 2/1 I was greeted with complaints about errors that arose from the changes I had made to the internal zone the night before and complaints that the changes I had made to the external zone had not gone through. I quickly reverted all the changes I had made to the internal zone, incremented the serial in both internal and external and reloaded named.

Why would have changes been reflected internally without incrementing the serial but not externally? Does the serial number only come into play when a slave queries the master not when the host hits the server for resolution?

```
Jan 29 04:02:09 xxxx named[3983]: zone xxxx/IN: loaded serial 2012012702
Jan 29 04:02:09 xxxx named[3983]: zone xxxx/IN: sending notifies (serial 2012012702)
Jan 29 04:02:09 xxxx named[3983]: zone xxxx.com/IN: loaded serial 2012012702
Jan 29 04:02:09 xxxx named[3983]: zone xxxx.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2012012702)

Jan 31 20:45:43 xxxx named[3983]: zone xxxx/IN: loaded serial 2012012702
Jan 31 20:45:43 xxxx named[3983]: zone xxxx/IN: sending notifies (serial 2012012702)
Jan 31 20:45:43 xxxx named[3983]: zone xxxx.com/IN: loaded serial 2012012702
Jan 31 20:45:43 xxxx named[3983]: zone xxxx.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2012012702)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The slave consults the serial number to check whether it needs to load new data. If it's higher than the one it already knows (following the meaning of "higher" defined in the RFC which allows for serial number wraparounds) it tries to update its copy of the zone.

The master server just starts serving what's in the zone file after you tell it to reload, regardless of what the serial number says.